# Form helpers with mustache in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mustache

I'm pretty new to Mustache. I have the following Mustache template in my Rails 3.2.5 app @ `app/templates/new.mustache`:

```
<h1>Add a new record</h1>
{{> form}}
```

I want to reuse the form for both the new + edit, so I have the following in `app/templates/_form.mustache`:

```
<%= form_for @record do |f| %>
  <dl class="form">
    <dt><%= f.label :name %></dt>
    <dd><%= f.text_field :name %></dd>
  </dl>
<% end %>
```

That's obviously not a Mustache template. I can't find any way to use Rails' form helpers using Mustache. Other that going back to ERB, I'd like to see if there's a way around it.

**QUESTION:** How do I use Rails' form helpers when I'm using Mustache instead of ERB?

Thanks!!!
  V

Answer (score 0):

Mustache is supposed to be logicless. When I use it, I have been building forms manually.